# Change value in mysql with query

Tags: mysql

I need to make an query in mysql like:

If my users did not sign in last 30 days, change the value of the credits to 0:

I tryed:

```
update users set coins = 0 where online > date_sub(now(), interval 30 day);
```

but this has changed to all users.. what is wrong?

Comment: i assume $id is userid

`UPDATE USERS SET coins = 0 WHERE online > date_sub(now(), interval 30 day) AND id = $id`

Comment: whats the datatype of online column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE users SET coins = 0 
WHERE online > date_sub(now(), interval 30 day);
```

will update all users that have `online` (presumably last logon) in the last 30 days. What you want is probably;

```
UPDATE users SET coins = 0 
WHERE online < date_sub(now(), interval 30 day);
```

...which does the reverse.

A simple way to check which users will be updated is to just use a select with the same condition so you can check manually that the result is reasonable;

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE online < date_sub(now(), interval 30 day);
```